# Oracle ADF - Tomcat 6.x - MySql 5.5 - Navigation Is Not Happening

Tags: mysql, tomcat6, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We developed a Oracle ADF web app using

- jDeveloper 11.1.2.4
- MySql 5.5

We successfully deployed our application onto Tomcat 6.x. But our problem is page navigation is not happening on tomcat server. We have first.jsf in that we have a button when ever I press this button I should get second.jsf, But am not getting. We checked our application on Integrated WLS it is working fine(Page Navigation is happening).

Please help us.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the URL that you are using to call the page?
It is has .jspx or .jsf at the end, try the same URL without that extension - so just http://...../first

Comment: Thanks a lot Shay. Am using all .jsf pages no jsp and jspx. Your solution is working. Navigation is happening if am using http://localhost:7777/MySqlApp2Tmct/faces/first this url as you suggested. Navigation is not happening if am using http://localhost:7777/MySqlApp2Tmct/faces/first.jsf this. Can you please tell me why like this???

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I was experimenting something similar on  Tomcat. To be honest, I can't point you the exact solution because I am not in front of the computer right now , but try to test navigation using fragments, not pages. Also, you may try navigation using facelets vs one using jsp. I remember one of these combinations was working.